# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property creates table with create but not with update

Tags: hibernate, hbm2ddl

The database table is NOT auto-created by the `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` settings.

It works for `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StrutsPractice"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mysessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/hbm/person.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="d" class="com.DAO.PersonDAO">
    <property name="sf" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

If table does not exist in the database then it should be created automatically.

Comment: Hibernate version?

Comment: Hibernate version is 4.0.0.Final

Comment: Change your dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect then try

Answer (score 1):

Possible values for `hbm2ddl.auto` and their description is as follows:

`create` - create a schema

`update` - update existing schema

`validate` - validate existing schema

`create-drop` - create and drop the schema automatically when a session is starts and ends